# AppCache 'miss' when file is loaded from remote domain in script?

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache

We use [Appcache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) of our [SubToMe](https://www.subtome.com/#/) button.

The benefit of loading the code once from the server and then keeping everything in the user browser is exactly what we want and it works grear. By loading in Chrome, you'll see in the dev console that all files are loaded the first time, and if you refresh that no other file is ever loaded.

However, the button is meant to be loaded form other sites like on a [blog](http://blog.superfeedr.com). The html button has a onclick listener which will just add a `script` element with an `src` point to `https://www.subtome.com/load.js`. For some reason, this file is not loaded via Appcache, even though it is in the manifest and if you get it directly (by putting its url in the browser bar), then it *is* fetched from AppCache.

Anyone knows how we can force the browsers to use the Appcache version when loaded from a 3rd party site? Or is that not possible with Appcache.

Answer (score 0):

"Over SSL, all resources in the manifest must respect the same-origin policy."

See http://appcachefacts.info

Comment: Well, I interpret(ed) that as "Over SSL on appache'd sites, all resources must respect same-origin policy", but in our case, the site from which the load.js is loaded is not the one stored in appcache.

Comment: And it says that Chrome behaves differently... which in our case is not true, Chrome does *also* load from the site, despite AppCache (which it shouldn't if that point was applying).